# Metodo getSupportFragmentManager no funciona en Fragment

Tags: android

Tendo esta funcion en un Activity que me funciona bien.

```
 private void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance( new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            // +1 because January is zero
            final String selectedDate = day + " / " + (month+1) + " / " + year;
            anadirfecha.setText(selectedDate);
        }
    });
    newFragment.show( getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

Pero cuando la pongo en un Fragment la palabra getSupportFragmentManager() sale en rojo y me dice:"

```
Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager' in 'FragmentN'
```

Como lo puedo solucionar.
Gracias y saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si te encuentras dentro de un Fragment debes usar el contexto para llamar el  método  `getSupportFragmentManager()`, por lo tanto debes realizarlo de esta forma usando como contexto la activity que carga el fragment usando `getActivity()`:

```
newFragment.show( getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

Si te encuentras dentro de una Activity asegura usar el import:

```
 newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

pero si te encuentras dentro de un Dialogo usa `getChildFragmentManager()` :

```
newFragment.show( getChildFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

Comment: Eso tampoco funciona, ya lo he probado y sigue igual

Comment: Veo que es una ACtivity pero con un Dialogo, usa getChildFragmentManager() edite mi respuesta. @FernandoDelgadoFernandez

Comment: Ya me funciono como dijistes muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente @FernandoDelgadoFernandez , recuerda marcar como solución la respuesta que solucione la pregunta, revisa [tour], saludos.